# Movie about the inheritance of a magic toy store

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

A movie where a employee that works in a magic toy store is notified by the employer that he will give the store to her. He notes that she wanted a change of career, but is playing the piano. He is now ill and says that he will die because it is the time.

Meanwhile they are hiring a lawyer who doesn't believe in magic so the toys don't show to him. At the end of the movie he starts to believe that magic is real just in time to save the store from depression, because the new owner does no have the emotion to administer the store.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this movie?  Was it live-action or animated?

Comment: @DavidW Live action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [*Mr. Magorium's Wonder Emporium*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457419/) (2007).  The employee (Natalie Portman) is a pianist to whom Edward Magorium (Dustin Hoffman) will leave the store.  Justin Bateman plays Henry Weston, the accountant hired to arrange the transfer of the shop who does not believe it's magical.

Quoting the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Magorium%27s_Wonder_Emporium#Plot):

> When Molly becomes upset about her inability to properly run the store, the Emporium 'throws a tantrum', assaulting everyone inside with the toys until Mr. Magorium calms it down. **Molly realizes that Mr. Magorium is going to die**, so she rushes him to a hospital until he is discharged the next day. She then attempts to prevent Mr. Magorium's departure by showing him the joys of life. Back at the store, Mr. Magorium uses the stage notes of Shakespeare's King Lear to make a point about the natural simplicity of death before dying himself. **Believing herself to be incapable of owning a magical store, Molly puts the Emporium up for sale, and the store loses all its magic**.
>
> Henry meets Molly to draw up the sale papers, where he sees the Congreve Cube and asks her about it. When Molly confesses her complete faith in the store, the block flies around the store. After witnessing this, Henry faints with shock. When he awakes and questions Molly, she tells him that it was a dream. **He then learns Molly made the cube fly and he believes in her**, realizing Molly can be anything if she believes in herself.